# How to manipulate string items in a 3d list in python? (without numpy)

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have a 3d list 6 items long and 6 items wide, which is a list of lists of a list of strings.

```
lst = [   [['A'],['A'],['B'],['B'],['A'],['A']],
          [['B'],['B'],['A'],['A'],['B'],['B']],
          [['A'],['A'],['B'],['B'],['A'],['A']],
          [['B'],['B'],['A'],['A'],['B'],['B']],
          [['A'],['A'],['B'],['B'],['A'],['A']],
          [['B'],['B'],['A'],['A'],['B'],['B']],
  ]
```

I want to move the strings into other locations on the list, but I know I'm not using the right code:

```
lst.insert([1][0][0], 'A')
```

gives me a `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

I know how to add items by doing this:

```
lst2 = lst[0][0]

lst2.append('A')
```

(adds another 'A' string to the first item)

I want to perform various actions on the lowest list like:

- add/remove strings to that list,
- check how many string items are in that list
- move 'A' or 'B' strings to different locations so that they have multiple strings.
- Check to see what the first string is in the list is

I am very new to programming and I am just starting to understand how to use 2d lists.

How do I accomplish this without any additional modules or libraries?

Comment: No offense, but numpy is actually quite useful! It only takes a second to install and import.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me clarify this line:

> `lst.insert([1][0][0], 'A')`

The insert method expects an `int` argument for the index. If you want to insert an element in a multidimensional list it should be done as:

```
lst[1][0].insert(0, 'A')
```

After all, it is a list of list (of lists). Only if you look at an inner index (defined by 2 coordinates), will you get a simple list (of strings in this case). You can then insert a string element to this simple list, by calling the `insert()` method.

> check how many string items are in that list

```
count = 0
for d2 in lst: #d2 is a 2d list (an element of a 3d list)
    for d1 in d2: # d1 - 1 dimensional
        count += len(d1)
```

Here, I have gone through each of the lowermost-level (simple) lists using a nested loop, counted how many elements are there in each and added them up.

> move 'A' or 'B' strings to different locations so that they have multiple strings.

Say I want to move the element from `[3][2][0]` to `[1][2][1]`. I would insert it in the new position and then delete from the old.

```
element = lst[3][2][0]         # the task can be accomplished without using another variable, but this is for better understanding
lst[1][2].insert(1, element)   # inserting
lst[3][2].pop(0)               # deleting
```

The element could even be moved to a position like `[1][2]`. So there would be one string along with the other 'sub-lists'

> Check to see what the first string is in the list is

Do you mean `lst[0][0][0]`.